# Using JQuery to open multiple other tabs on initial page load [MobileSafari]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

I've created a webpage that, when loaded, opens up two more webpages.
This works fine on Safari (with pop-ups enabled). However, when I access this page through MobileSafari (with pop-ups enabled) on the iPhone simulator, it will not open the new tabs.

Has anyone found a method of allowing a webpage to open new webpages on load within mobile safari before?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="site" href="bbcNews/www.bbc.co.uk/news/index.html" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
    <a class="site" href="ebay/www.ebay.com/index.html" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
    <script>
        $('a').each(function () {
            var clk = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            clk.initMouseEvent("click", false, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
            this.dispatchEvent(clk);
        });
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/[jquery version here]/jquery.min.js"
    language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```